# Why added Data Connections in Server Explorer doesn't stay in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, oracle11g, odp.net

I added a connection to Oracle database under Server Explorer's Data Connections inside Visual Studio Premium 2012. But after I close the solution and re-open again, the added data connection is gone. How can I keep it there?

**update:**

I found that the connection information is actually stored at `%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ServerExplorer\DefaultView.SEView` but `Server Explorer` doesn't seem to read and display it.

Answer (score 0):

%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ServerExplorer\DefaultView.SEView
if you delete this file, then it is created again and it has no use.
Just delete your web.config or other config files like app.config connection strings that you don't need them again.
I test it for about half a day and deleting the unneeded connection strings from config file help me not loading again that connection string in server explorer of visual studio 2012. Wish you luck

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood what I want. I actually want the Server Explorer to keep the connection I had before so I don't have to re-create it every time.